The template deduction for rvalue reference template and literal argument in C++
I am reading about template argument deduction, the definition of P and A is:

Template argument deduction attempts to determine template arguments (types for type template parameters Ti, templates for template template parameters TTi, and values for non-type template parameters Ii), which can be substituted into each parameter P to produce the type deduced A

On that page, we have this example:

If P is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter (so-called forwarding references), and the corresponding function call argument is an lvalue, the type lvalue reference to A is used in place of A for deduction (Note: this is the basis for the action of std::forward. Note: in class template argument deduction, template parameter of a class template is never a forwarding reference(since C++17)):
template<class T>
int f(T&&);       // P is an rvalue reference to cv-unqualified T (forwarding reference)

template<class T>
int g(const T&&); // P is an rvalue reference to cv-qualified T (not special)

int main()
{
    int i;
    int n1 = f(i); // argument is lvalue: calls f<int&>(int&) (special case)
    int n2 = f(0); // argument is not lvalue: calls f<int>(int&&)
 
//  int n3 = g(i); // error: deduces to g<int>(const int&&), which
                   // cannot bind an rvalue reference to an lvalue
}


In int n2 = f(0), when we substitute the template argument into the pattern, we get P=T&&, and 0 is a literal, so A is an rvalue, so how does it deduce that T is int?

EDIT
First, we need to solve T&&=int for T, 0 is not lvalue, so we don't need to change int to int&, then in the deduction, we discard the reference of the left hand side, hence we get T=int.

From the same page: "Before deduction begins, the following adjustments to P and A are made: ... 3) If P is a reference type, the referenced type is used for deduction." So P becomes T after this adjustment, and A is int (the type of the literal 0), and so therefore T == int.

@吴yuer your EDIT looks more like an answer, and so should be posted as such. See Can I answer my own question?

In the page in the question,we want to deduce the T in int n2 = f(0) it says that before it conduct the deduction, it first adjust the equation(here is T&&=int)to solve, since 0 is a rvalue, we don't need to change the int to int&, then we conduct the deduction, in the deduction, the left hand side's reference is discarded, so we get T=int
